# Computers "Member Of" VBS Script

Tags: vbscript

I have the following VBS script and it has been very helpfull when adding multiple new computer accounts to a school that I work for. I would like to know if anyone can modify the script so that it can also add a group to the "Members Of" tab of the newly created computer accounts. Thanks

```
' Author Guy Thomas http://computerperformance.co.uk/
' Found at http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/vbscript_computer_spreadsheet.htm
' Version 1.2 - May 2010
' ------------------------------------------------------' 
Option Explicit
Dim strComputer, strOU, strSheet, intRow
Dim objRootLDAP, objContainer, objComputer, objShell
Dim objExcel, objSpread 

' -----------------------------------------------'
' Important change OU= and strSheet to reflect your domain
' -----------------------------------------------'

strOU = "OU=New Computers,OU=Workstations,OU=123,OU=Site Based Computer Accounts ," ' Note the comma
strSheet = "C:\Documents and Settings\257466\Desktop\Create Computer Accounts\Computer Accounts.xls" 

' Bind to Active Directory, Computers container.
Set objRootLDAP = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
Set objContainer = GetObject("LDAP://" & strOU & _
objRootLDAP.Get("defaultNamingContext")) 

' Open the Excel spreadsheet
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objSpread = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strSheet)
intRow = 2 'Row 1 often containes headings

' Here is the loop that cycles through the cells
Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
   strComputer = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value

   ' Build the actual computer.
   Set objComputer = objContainer.Create("Computer", _
   "cn=" &   strComputer)
   objComputer.Put "sAMAccountName", strComputer & "$"
   objComputer.Put "userAccountControl", 4096
   objComputer.SetInfo 
   intRow = intRow + 1
Loop
objExcel.Quit 

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Does [this forum thread](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1246185&page=1) help?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment from oracle certified professional, I was able to come up with the following to add the created computers to a group.

```
' Added section to add the computer to the group
' Comment out with if not needed
Dim objGroup, strGroup
strGroup = "OU=New Computers,OU=Workstations,OU=123,dc=company,dc=com"
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & strGroup)
objGroup.add objComputer.adspath
```

Just place the above lines between objComputer.SetInfo and intRow = intRow + 1 and it will add the computer to a group.